# HTML Pre tag is not displaying full line

Tags: html

I am using `<pre>` tag in my html page but it not displaying the full line. What I wanted to display is the hwole two below lines:

```
    Hello Wish you all the best. This is just a testing of multiline as it is cutting the print work order.Multi formatting within email notifications and work order comments/notes
    End Line. Last Comment.
```

But it is only displaying

```
 <pre>
    Hello Wish you all the best. This is just a testing of multiline as 
    End Line. Last Comment.
    </pre>
```

Does the pre tag has fixed widht or something? Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

You would need an overflow for the hidden stuff to show up in case the overflow was hidden. This will add a scrollbar.

```
pre {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Or you would need to wrap the pre tag if scrolling is not an option. For that use

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Now the line will wrap and show in the next line while still maintaining the white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code you gave, wrapped in a pre tag. Looks fine from my house.

```html
<pre>
Hello Wish you all the best. This is just a testing of multiline as it is cutting the print work order.Multi formatting within email notifications and work order comments/notes
    End Line. Last Comment.
    </pre>
```